# Using cout to print starting from a specific place

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So lets say I had a string that was

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title><head>
```

and so
I'm using the `str.find();` to find where the title tag starts and it gives me the correct position but how would I go about printing just the

```
301 Moved Permanently
```

My code:

```
    string requestedPage = page.GetBody(); //Get the body of a page and store as string "requestedPage"

    int subFromBeg = requestedPage.find("<title>"); //Search for the <title> tag
    int subFromEnd = requestedPage.find("</title>"); //Search for the </title> tag



    std::cout << requestedPage; //before

    requestedPage.substr( subFromBeg, subFromEnd );

    std::cout << requestedPage; //after
```

Comment: I'll add my whole code after I try something

Comment: Please don't show us your whole original program. Please reduce your program to the absolutely **smallest** possible **complete** program that still demonstrates the problem, then show us *that*. See http://sscce.org for more info. Hint: For this problem, if the sample program is longer than about 10 lines, it is probably too long.

Comment: note: that's not a complete program.

Comment: @THUNDERGROOVE : [This](http://ideone.com/lkv9q) would have been a good, [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
requestedPage.substr( subFromBeg, subFromEnd );
```

should be

```
requestedPage = requestedPage.substr( subFromBeg, subFromEnd );
```

`std::string::substr` doesn't modify the string, it returns a modified copy of the string.

Comment: Ohhhhh this all makes sense now! You guys are such a big help!!

Answer (score 0):

[substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) is how I would do it. Something like `cout << str.substr(str.find("title") + 6, 21);` would get you a 21-character string starting at 6 characters after 'title' (hopefully, I counted my indices right, but you get the idea).

Comment: I tried that and after determining how much to remove from ether end of the string and doing it it printed out everything still

Comment: @THUNDERGROOVE: Then you didn't use `substr` properly.